# Oracle SQL: Foreign Key Target Table

Tags: sql, oracle, key

I want to write an SQL to check out FK'S. What I got so far:

```
SELECT OWNER,
       CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
       TABLE_NAME,
       R_OWNER,
       R_CONSTRAINT_NAME
  FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS
 WHERE     OWNER = 'XXX'
       AND TABLE_NAME = 'XXX'
       AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R'
```

The problem: I don't see where the FK is mapping to. You have R_OWNER and R_CONSTRAINT_NAME, but no R_TABLE. Is there anyway this can be done by writing SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED.

This gives you what you want:

```
select
    cc.owner,
    cc.constraint_name, 
    cc.table_name, 
    cc.column_name, 
    c.r_owner,
    c_pk.table_name r_table_name, 
    c_pk.constraint_name r_pk
from all_cons_columns cc
join all_constraints c on cc.owner = c.owner and cc.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
join all_constraints c_pk on c.r_owner = c_pk.owner and c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name
where c.constraint_type = 'R' 
and cc.owner = 'XXX'
and cc.table_name = 'XXX';
```

Comment: One question: what's the purpose of joining all_constraints with all_constraints?

Comment: Well, you get different rows from the same view in order to join them together. There's nothing unusual to use the same table or view in the same query if it's for the purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You can get list of all existing foreign keys :

```
         SELECT RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME FK_Name,
               KF.TABLE_SCHEMA FK_Schema,
               KF.TABLE_NAME FK_Table,
               KF.COLUMN_NAME FK_Column,
               RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME PK_Name,
               KP.TABLE_SCHEMA PK_Schema,
               KP.TABLE_NAME PK_Table,
               KP.COLUMN_NAME PK_Column,
               RC.MATCH_OPTION MatchOption,
               RC.UPDATE_RULE UpdateRule,
               RC.DELETE_RULE DeleteRule
         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC
             JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KF ON RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KF.CONSTRAINT_NAME
             JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KP ON RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = KP.CONSTRAINT_NAME;
```

Comment: On google i have searched and its available in Oracle also, refer to link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.0/information-schema.html

Comment: No it's not. Don't believe a random hit on Google without verifying. [Read the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/toc.htm) instead

Comment: I already tried using information_schema, it's not available.

Comment: Your link is for the **MySQL** manual, not for the Oracle database.